# Count the number of specific objects in a OrderedDict structure

Tags: python, counting

I create the following OrderedDict:

```
import collections

class obj1():
    def __init__(self):
          self.aa = 22
          self.bb = 23

class obj2():
    def __init__(self):
          self.dd = 22
          self.ee = 23

my_test = collections.OrderedDict()

my_test['1'] = obj1
my_test['2'] = obj1
my_test['3'] = obj1
my_test['4'] = obj2
```

and this is the outcome:

```
my_test
Out[41]: 
OrderedDict([('1', __main__.obj1),
             ('2', __main__.obj1),
             ('3', __main__.obj1),
             ('4', __main__.obj2)])
```

As it can be noticed, there are two types of object: `obj1` and `obj2`. I would like to know if it is possible to know the number of `obj1` (i.e. 3) in that OrderedDict structure.

I was thinking about a cycle over all the tuples. This approach has, however, two problems:

1. I do not know how to extract the object name,
2. it seems no so straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.Counter` for this!

This will count all the instances, and give them as keys in a dict, mapping to their count in the iterator. Since Python `type` objects are hashable, this works.

With your previous example:

```py
counts = collections.Counter(my_test.values())
print(counts[obj1])
>>> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for a way to count the occurrences of each class in the dictionary, right ?

```py
occurrences = {}
for i in my_test:
  class_name = i.__class__.__name__
  occurrences[class_name] = occurrences.get(class_name, 0) + 1
```

That should give you a dictionary containing the classes as keys and their occurrences as values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another great class found in `collections`: [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
counts = collections.Counter(my_test.values())
print(counts)       # prints something like Counter({<class '__main__.obj1'>: 3, <class '__main__.obj2'>: 1})
print(counts[obj1]) # prints 3
```